# wsimport don't generate client classes with geotoolkit

Tags: jax-ws, wsimport

if I build a jax-ws web service including objects coming from geotoolkit library, when I run the wsimport tool to generate the client, I get this errors:
[wsimport] [ERROR] undefined simple type 'actuate'

[wsimport] line 5 of http://localhost:8080/jaxws/myservice?xsd=1

[wsimport] [ERROR] undefined simple type 'show'

[wsimport] line 13 of http://localhost:8080/jaxws-myapp/myservice?xsd=1

[wsimport] [ERROR] undefined simple type 'type'

[wsimport] line 17 of http://localhost:8080/jaxws-myapp/myservice?xsd=1.

any workaround?
I can't find a proper way to tell wsimport to read the xsd definition from a different url than the on-line one (the problem is that some namespaces specified by the wsdl refer to urls not available)

Comment: probably the problem is that those objects should be defined at http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink, but the xsd is not available there, tather it is available at http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink.xsd. So I tried to workaround by overriding the URL, with an XMLCatalogue option for the wsimport, here is the catalogeu.xml that I used:

Comment: <!DOCTYPE catalog
  PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD XML Catalogs V1.1//EN"
         "http://www.oasis-open.org/committees/entity/release/1.1/catalog.dtd">
<catalog xmln="urn:oasis:names:tc:entity:xmlns:xml:catalog">
    <rewriteURI uriStartString="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" rewritePrefix="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink.xsd"/>
</catalog>
 but it doesn't seem to be working

Answer (score 0):

At the end I found how to write an OASIS XML catalog file to workaround the problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE catalog PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD Entity Resolution XML Catalog V1.0//EN"
 "http://www.oasis-open.org/committees/entity/release/1.0/catalog.dtd">
<catalog xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:entity:xmlns:xml:catalog">
 <system systemId="http://localhost:8080/jaxws-myapp/myservice?xsd=1" uri="file:///c:/myxsd"/>
</catalog>
```

This way wsimport overrides the in-line xsd with the local one, where i simplified the types (originally they were enumeration) to xs:string